# golang command line flag syntax form

Tags: go, command-line, command-line-arguments

I want my go program to only accept command line flags with = form.

Those are forms from [the flag documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/flag#hdr-Command_line_flag_syntax) that are accepted currently:

```
-flag
--flag   // double dashes are also permitted
-flag=x
-flag x  // non-boolean flags only
```

This is what I want my program to accept:

```
--flag=x
-flag=x
```

Basically what I want to accomplish: `go run . --color=blue "String I wanna color"` here `len(os.Args[1:])` should be 2.

Running with space: `go run . --color blue "String I wanna color"` here `len(os.Args[1:]` should be equal to 3.

I've only been learning programming for few weeks, I hope this question makes sense and has solution.

I read go flag documentation and looked into functions inside flag package to figure out solution, but I couldn't find anything related to my problem expect only boolean flag accepts form with `=` sign.

Comment: Why do you care if the user uses `=` or not?

Comment: The syntax Go supports isn't arbitrary. It's standard behavior shared by many, many programs. As an end user I expect programs to support both `--flag=x` and `--flag x`. I would encourage you to accept it as is and not try to disable it.

Comment: I don't care but the curriculum where I am learning go is testing flags form with space and will not accept this. So I guess I have to use bunch of if statments with os.Args() instead of flags.

Comment: The package flag from stdlib cannot be forced to behave the way you want.